TailwindCSS classes not working after installing through CLI (no framework used)
I have installed TailwindCSS through CLI but my classes are not working. I am not working with any framework and simply learning Tailwind.
In my style.css the code is
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


In my tailwind.config.js the code is
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

The package.json file's code is
{
  "name": "mega-project-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}


The output.css file is properly linked with index.html and here is the code for index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tailwind Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent" class="flex justify-items-center items-center gap-2">
      <div class="bg-red-500 h-8 w-8"></div>
      <div class="bg-blue-700 h-8 w-8"></div>
      <div class="bg-yellow-400 h-8 w-8"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

My folder structure is in below image
Folder Structure
Things I already tried by checking similar other problems on Stack Overflow are here:
I tried runing npm run build but got error.
I also tried to change
From
 @tailwind base;
 @tailwind components;
 @tailwind utilities;

To
@import "tailwind/base";
@import "tailwind/components";
@import "tailwind/utilities";

but still my classes didn't work.

Though its unclear to me what your actual problem is, you seem to forgot to build the output css
should be similiar to:
npx tailwindcss -i ./styles.css -o ./output.css --watch
as described here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Thanks after your answer I searched a bit more and found that I need to re-run that build command every time, also found that I can add it to package.json. Thanks a lot my problem is solved. Sorry using tailwindcss for very first time.

You´re welcome :) im glad it helped. the example above uses a --watch that listens to changes in the input file and automatically builds then, maybe this is sth. you are looking for
